# Django model single instance per foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django class that is supposed to manage sending some jobs through an API to a server for computing and then return the result (using a signal to indicate job is done and result can be taken).

Let's say we have an equation model like this:

```
class equation(models.Model):
    calculator = ForeignKey(calculatorFarm)

    def calculationFinished(self, sender, **kwargs):
        print('result is done!: '+ kwargs['result'])

    def calculate(self):
        calculatorFarm.calculationDone.connect(self.calculationFinished)
        self.calculator.startCalc('2+2')
```

On the other side, the calculatorFarm I have something like the following:

```
import externalAPI
class calculatorFarm(models.Model):
    serverAddr = model.GenericIPAddressFioeld()
    calculationDone = Signal(providing_args=['result'])
    client = None

    def on_update(self, notification):
        if notification.mode == notification.JOB_FINISHED:
            self.calculationDone.send(sender=self.__class__, result=notification.result)

    def startCalc(self, equation):
        if self.client is None:
            self.client = externalAPI.connect(serverAddr)
        return self.client.add_calculation(equation, self.on_update)
```

I define only one calculatorFarm through the admin (only one IP doing the calculations) and associate it to two different equations.

What I expected to happen is: the first equation sees that the client variable of calculatorFarm is None and therefore connects it for the first time. The second equation already finds the client is not None (connected) and proceeds to add the job inmediately.

What is happening: everytime I call the startCalc method the client is None and tries to connect, the server doesn't allow this so I get an error.

I've already tried:
- saving all the model with self.save() inside the if after I connect the client
- defining the client cvariable inside the **init**() method

Comment: Investigating this I noticed that if I take two different equation models with the same calculator foreign key the statement  

a.calculator is b.calculator  

returns False  

Therefore django is creating two instances of calculatorFarm (even if it has the same Foreign Key.  

How can I force the calculatorFarm to be the exact same Object if the foreign key is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I force the calculatorFarm to be the exact same Object if the foreign key is the same?*

I don't think that's the right approach. Stepping back for a moment, a Django `Model` instance is meant to represent a row in the database, and its behavior is defined by the values for the columns of that row. That's why model instance equality (`__eq__`) is defined by looking at the primary key field, not the object ids. Trying to force object equality would change the semantics of the ORM.

Really, though, this isn't a Django issue. All you want to do is cache existing connections to your service, which can be done using one of several design patterns. A straightforward approach might look like this:

```
class ServiceConnector(object):
    connections = {}

    @staticmethod
    def get_connection(ip):
        if ip not in ServiceConnector.connections:
            ServiceConnector.connections[ip] = externalAPI.connect(ip)

        return ServiceConnector.connections[ip]

class calculatorFarm(models.Model):
    serverAddr = model.GenericIPAddressField()

    def startCalc(self, equation):
        client = ServiceConnector.get_service(self.serverAddr)
        return client.add_calculation(equation, self.on_update)
```

I think something like this would be a lot cleaner than trying to force model instance object equality.

Comment: Excellent! thanks a lot! now its working with class that manages connections in a static method